# jquery ajax call and hide function

Tags: javascript, ajax, load, jquery

I have the following script that works ok on the first page load. I am then calling a page again and the hide function does not work, and certain formatting is lost..

Any ideas. Is there a way using jquery live or delegate for instance.

```
$(document).ready( function() {

    // Hide all subfolders at startup
    $(".php-file-tree").find("UL").hide();

    // Expand/collapse on click
    $(".pft-directory A").click( function() {
        $(this).parent().find("UL:first").slideToggle("medium");
        if( $(this).parent().attr('className') == "pft-directory" ) return false;
    });

});
```

How do I execute `find("UL").hide();` again on ajax call.

Comment: what ajax call? you would do $(".php-file-tree").find("UL").hide(); again as part of the completion routine for your ajax

Comment: Hi Scott. I am calling a div from another page to a div within my index.php. It works when I first load, but when I call the div this is when the problem happens. I dont know if that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

In the ajax success handler just execute the below line

```
$(".php-file-tree").find("UL").hide();
```